# Ansible 2.3.1.0: Enable repo on CENTOS 7

Tags: ansible

In order to install php7 seven I need to enable remi-php71 repo using following command:

```
yum-config-manager --enable remi-php71
```

How can I do it in an ansible task?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can do this to issue that specific shell command:

```
- name: enable remi-php71
  shell: yum-config-manager --enable remi-php71
```

Although it is probably better to declare the yum repo itself via something like:

```
- name: Add remi-php71
  yum_repository:
    name: remi-php71
    description: Remi's PHP 7.1 RPM repository for Enterprise Linux $releasever - $basearch
    mirrorlist: http://rpms.remirepo.net/enterprise/$releasever/php71/mirror
    enabled: yes
    gpgcheck: 1
    gpgkey: http://rpms.remirepo.net/RPM-GPG-KEY-remi
```

Docs [here](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/shell_module.html) and [here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/yum_repository_module.html).

Comment: Notice, while "yum-config-manager" may have some issue (with return code), you also need to declare the "remi-safe" repository which provides common dependencies for all PHP versions.

Answer (score 16):

I had the same need (but for 5.6).  Following the advice in the discussion [here](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-modules-extras/issues/2384) I used the following:

```
- name: enable remi-php56
  ini_file:
    dest: /etc/yum.repos.d/remi.repo
    section: remi-php56
    option: enabled
    value: 1
```

The advantage over using `yum_repository` is I don't have to maintain the definition - I install the remi repos from the RPM he provides.  The advantage over the `shell` variant (which should probably be `command` anyway) is I don't need to run commands and I don't need the yum utils installed just for this

Answer (score 2):

You can also enable the repository only during the installation process:

```
- name: Install PHP packages
  yum:
    name:
      - php
      - php-cli
      - php-common
      - php-devel
      - php-fpm
      - php-gd
      - php-ldap
      - etc...
    state: latest
    enablerepo: "remi,remi-php71"
```